# How to search for multiple full and partial values in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, search, sql-like

I'm runnning an app running on a `Coldfusion8/MySQL 5.0.88` database.

The app has a search form which users can use to search for product-IDs.

Right now my SQL statement looks like this:

```
  ...
  AND a.product_id LIKE <cfqueryparam value="%#form.s_product_id#%" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
```

Users are normally passing in a `single id`  or `partial id`, so I need this to work for both:

```
   123456 (full id)
   123 (partial id)
```

However, I also want to enable users to search for multiple IDs. So a user might enter:

```
   12345,233345,78876
```

**Question**:
I can clear out the spaces before submitting the form, but how do I make it so my MySQL search handler correclty identifies this as a list. If I just use `IN` instead of `LIKE` I will loose the partial_ID, won't I?

Comment: you may try `REGEXP UDF`: https://launchpad.net/mysql-udf-regexp

Comment: @Omesh: or I check for multiple values submitted in Coldfusion when running the query. If only a sinlge value I do `LIKE %value%`, if multiple values, I do `IN (value,value,value)`. would that work?

Comment: `LIKE` will work in all cases whereas `IN` will only work for exact matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So an effective ColdFusion solution could be:

```
    <cfquery name="your_query_name" datasource="your_datasource">
    SELECT column1, column2
    FROM a
    WHERE condition=whatever
    <cfif listlen(form.s_product_id)>
       AND (1=0 /* always false; for SQL syntax only */
       <cfloop list="#form.s_product_id#" index="variables.s_product_id_ii">
         OR a.product_id LIKE <cfqueryparam value="%#variables.s_product_id_ii#%" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" />
       </cfloop>)
    </cfif>
    </cfquery>
```

If 'a.product_id' is an integer field, consider casting it as VARCHAR

```
    CAST(a.product_id AS VARCHAR(50)) LIKE <cfqueryparam...
```

so this query won't break on different, stricter, databases.
Alternately, since you're splitting the form.s_product_id list into its component integers you could change the cfqueryparam cfsqltype to "cf_sql_integer".

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know about CAST, but I'm already using Varchar, as product_ids can be anything. Also, thanks for the (1=0). As I more or less ended up using your solution, you get the nod.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not into coldfusion, but you would need to split the list of IDs at the comma and build a query like this:

```
... AND (a.product_id LIKE '%12345%' OR a.product_id LIKE '%123%' OR a.product_id LIKE '%78876%') ...
```

Comment: Ok. That is a nice idea! Since there won't be that many entries, performance should also be ok.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
include('config.php');
if (!empty($_REQUEST['term'])) {

$term = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']);     

$sql ="Select product.id,costomer.name,costomer.mobile,product.cid,product.pname,product.model,product.date,product.harddisk,product.ram,product.damage,product.driver,product.status from product INNER JOIN costomer
ON costomer.cid=product.cid WHERE id LIKE '%".$term."%'
OR name LIKE '%".$term."%',
OR pname LIKE '%".$term."%',
OR model LIKE '%".$term."%',
OR statusLIKE '%".$term."%',";

$r_query = mysql_query($sql); 
?>

<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r_query)){  


echo '<tr><td>' .$row['id'].'</td>';  
echo '<td>'.$row['name'].'</td>';
echo '<td>' .$row['pname'].'-'.$row['model'].'</td>';  
echo '<td>'.$row['mobile'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row['status'].'</td>';


}  
echo '</tr>';
}

?>
```